# Extract integer value from a character string

Tags: r

I have a character in the form `"RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2412E-02"` saved in a variable. I want to extract the integer value as `0.012412`. Please suggest the syntax to do so in R.

Comment: You should add the R tag to your question so that people can know what technology the question relates to.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, put up some code, it's usually good when people know you tried something, like a string split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# function to extract number from a string
f = function(x) {
y = unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
y = as.numeric(y)
y = y[!is.na(y)]
y }


# having one value
x = "RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2412E-02"

f(x)

# [1] 0.012412


# having multiple values
dt = data.frame(x = c("RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2412E-02",
                      "RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2 = 1.5412E-02",
                      "RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3 = 2.2412E-02"), stringsAsFactors = F)

dt$value = f(dt$x)

dt

#                                   x    value
# 1 RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2412E-02 0.012412
# 2 RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2 = 1.5412E-02 0.015412
# 3 RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3 = 2.2412E-02 0.022412
```

Comment: # importing value from a meta data file                                     
rad_mul_11 <- metadata[B11]
> show(rad_mul_11)
[1] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_11 = 3.3420E-04"
> f = function(rad_mul_11) {
+     y = unlist(strsplit(rad_mul_11, " "))
+     y = as.numeric(y)
+     y = y[!is.na(y)]
+     y }

Comment: actually am not getting the proper results

Comment: You have to post a few lines of your dataset that shows what format you have and what is the type of your varaible.

Comment: type is character, I tried the above mention solution but i think i am making some error.

Comment: No need to change the function. You have to post an example of your data (few rows) so I can see how to solve your problem.